# Item getting bigger when sliding ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to implement a list effect in android as the one displayed in the Ultravisual Iphone app :

[image]

The similar effect can be view on the Expo Milano 2015 app in android.

I would like the top item get bigger when sliding down the ListView.

I have no idea how this can be done... Is it an animation on the first item in the current view?

If someone has an example or a clue to achieve this, it will be great!

Thanks

Comment: Start by telling us what have you done so far. What do you have, your adapter, your layout etc etc.

Comment: I have already done the listview with a custom list_item.xml containing an imageView and texts.
The listView is well displayed with a custom adaptarer.
But so far all the items are displayed in same full size...

Answer (score 7):

Well I tried to achieve that effect and it looked like this:

[image]

First you need to start defining your max and min font size. I did this:

```
private final int MAX_FONTSIZE=50;
private final int MIN_FONTSIZE=12;
```

Next you need to save your screen total height. On your onCreate save it like this:

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    mScreenHeight = size.y;
```

Then override your listview onScroll event and do something like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if(listview.getChildCount()>0)
            for(int i=0;i<listview.getChildCount();i++)
            {
                float font = Math.min(Math.max(MAX_FONTSIZE - (float)(((MAX_FONTSIZE-MIN_FONTSIZE)/(mScreenHeight*0.3)))*Math.max(listview.getChildAt(i).getTop(),0),MIN_FONTSIZE),MAX_FONTSIZE);
                ((TextView)listview.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(font);
            }
        }
```

The `0.3` means that at about 30% of your screen it will always be the minimum font size. You can tweak that value for whatever you want. Remember that `listview.getChildAt(i)` will return the view that you inflate on your adapter. In my case it's just a simple textview, that's why it's safe to cast it to TextView. You might need to call findViewById to get your textview.

You also might need to make the TextView centered so it looks prettier.

**EDIT**:

Since op want to change the view's size (which should not be used with this code) here is some hack you can do. Start by changing your min/max constants to what you want (100 & 250). Then proceed to create a flag that controls if the listview is scrolling or not. On your onScrollStateChanged add this line `isScrolling= i == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL || i == SCROLL_STATE_FLING;` where `i` is the second parameter of the onScrollStateChanged. Next change the line to `if(listview.getChildCount()>0 && isScrolling)`. The next step is to change the view height. To do this you have to change it's layoutParams.

`listview.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Math.round(font * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));`

Remember this is, like I said, a simple hack. This is not, by far, the best solution to this. But since it's a complex thing to do let's stick with the basics.

Comment: Thank you, it look almost what I'm looking for! I think it is possible to apply a different size of the linearLayout instead of the font size. For v.getChildCount>0, v is representing the current ViewGroup displayed? I'm not able to get the LinearLayout of the root of item_list.xml with :
LinearLayout linear= ((LinearLayout) listViewItems.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.linear_layout));
There is something wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to get the root of the view don't call findViewById. listViewItems.getChildAt(i) will get you the root already. As for the v.getChildCount I've updated the answer. v stands for your listview.

Comment: :) Nice it is working!
But not totally as well as the textsize, I need to improve it.
Starting first to understand your
 float font = Math.min(Math.max(MAX_FONTSIZE - (float)(((MAX_FONTSIZE-MIN_FONTSIZE)/(mScreenHeight*0.3)))*Math.max(listview.getChildAt(i).getTop(),0),MIN_FONTSIZE),MAX_FONTSIZE);
and adapt it to get my layout from 100dp to 250dp
thanks

Comment: Changing the view's size during scroll will recall scroll multiple times making it recursive and will consume a lot of memory. Also the views will all flicker a bit. The example you gave is using a scrollview rather than a listview and it's completely customized. What you're trying to achieve is quite hard to do and I suggest you that if you're not familiar with implementing your own control you stick with the basics.

Comment: Ok, that's what I saw when resizing the view...
I'll will take a look for implementing my own scrollview but as you same it seems to be hard to do.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your Hack is working! But as you said it is not the best solution, there are somes limitations (clipping, last items doesn't scroll).
So I starting to implement my own scrollView, I already have it with a scroll listener

Comment: Glad my solution enlighten you somehow. Good work implementing your own listview.