# Scaling RecyclerView item depending on it's position

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, scale

I'm trying to achieve RecyclerView like below:

[image]

Items are views of same type but with different scale. I've tried to call

```
view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);  view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
```

In `OnBindViewHolder` method of RecycleView adapter and also in ItemDecorator but each time behavior of list was unexpected.
What is best approach to achieve it? May be with some other control like PagerAdapter or other.

**UPD:** scaling factor depends on position of item in adapter and should not be changed while scrolling.

**UPD2:** Here is the code I've tried in OnBoundViewHolder:

```
int childCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
View view = holder.getView();

if (position == childCount){
    view.setScaleX(1f);
    view.setScaleY(1f);
} else if (position == childCount - 1){
    view.setScaleX(0.8f);
    view.setScaleY(0.8f);
} else if (position == childCount - 2){
    view.setScaleX(0.6f);
    view.setScaleY(0.6f);
}
else {
    view.setScaleX(0.4f);
    view.setScaleY(0.4f);
}
```

And here is the result(and it's changing while scrolling):

[image]

And the same code but in `ItemDecorator getItemOffsets`:

[image]

Comment: Is the scale dependent on the position of the item in the adapter? Or the scroll position of the item in the list?

Comment: I wrote something about that for listviews. You can have a look here and see if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26000069/3410697

Comment: Yes, scale depends on position in adapter. The last item is always has scale factor 1, last - 1 has factor 0.8f, last - 2 has factor 0.6 and others 0.4 f. Scale should not be changed while scrolling

Comment: could you post the full code of onBindViewHolder please? And also, please explain a bit more about what the unexpected behavior is?

Comment: Updated post with some details.

Comment: @PavloI. Any updated code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your basing the scale according to the position relative to the **amount of children inside the RecyclerView**

Remember, the recycler view will never have more children than are visible at the moment (+ some additional delta). It is NOT an indicator on how many items your recycler will display. For example, a recycler with 1000 items will only have a child count of about 6-7, depending on the size of each list item.

What you want to do is to compare the position against the **item count**

Here's a proposed fix:

```
int totalItems = getItemCount();
View view = holder.getView();

if (position == totalItems - 1){ // final position will equal total items - 1
    view.setScaleX(1f);
    view.setScaleY(1f);
} else if (position == totalItems - 2){
    view.setScaleX(0.8f);
    view.setScaleY(0.8f);
} else if (position == totalItems - 3){
    view.setScaleX(0.6f);
    view.setScaleY(0.6f);
}
else {
    view.setScaleX(0.4f);
    view.setScaleY(0.4f);
}
```

Hope this helps.